# Rotate Screen using PHP Exec

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I'm probably way out of my depth here - but trying to understand how I can interact with a Ubuntu Machine running XAMPP through PHP scripts. I'm writing a small web-app that will live completely offline and will function only as a office display screen.

Since there is the possibility that the user will connect the machine to a different screen I'd like there to be an ability to rotate the screen thats currently connected to the machine.

I was hoping something like this would work:

```
<?php

exec('xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left');

?>
```

But it would appear that this and a few other variants don't work at all - despite working well when typed into the terminal on the machine, rather than called via PHP.

Is there something I am missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A webserver responds to HTTP(S) requests and returns a response. This will execute on the webservers device, not the client... what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: If you are trying to rotate the screen of the person in control of the browser, you might want to look at starting with a basic shell script that runs on users PC in a terminal instead of a PHP coming from a webserver.

Comment: Yes I want the command to execute on the webserver - which is acting as both a remote user interface (for control) and also running a web-browser in kiosk mode to act as a display.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come searching - it would appear that the xrandr command needs to be changed slightly for this to work as I hoped.

Corrected code:

```
<?php

exec('xrandr -display :0.0 --output HDMI-1 --rotate left');

?>
```

Apologies if this seems like a very basic question - trying to learn lots in a short space of time....